# Jenkins CVS update delay

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, cvs

I'm having approximately a 30 mins delay after a commit to get the changes detected by a CVS polling (update) in a Jenkins Job.

Do you have please any idea how can I manage to get the changes directly detected by a manual build?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is your jenkins job configured to poll more frequently?

The frequency is defined in "Poll SCM" field of the job configuration and the most frequent would be to poll every second with the standard cron pattern of `* * * * *`.

Comment: I tried to poll every 2 minutes then every 15 minutes but still can't detect any changes. It's after approximately half an hour that the job detect changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an inventory of your nodes to check the "# of executors". Is it possible that other builds are causing your CVS delay?  I would also double check that the job's Advanced Project Options doesn't include a "Quiet Period" setting.

Answer (score 0):

Check the time synchronization between your CVS host and Jenkins host. Exact timestamps are used for CVS polling and are created on the Jenkins host, without regard for what time the CVS host currently has set (the 2 are assumed to be roughly similar). Your issue sounds like it may be the 2 servers being out be 30 minutes (or a multiple of 30).